# Paypal Express Checkout Recurring Payments Custom Start Date

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am using Paypal Express Checkout to set up a recurring payment. The issue that i am being blocked on is that i cant figure out how to pass the start date from my site all the way through to the `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` function. `$_SESSION` isn't working so i looked at the API and there is a field you can set in `SetExpressCheckout` called `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM`, however its only for transcations including direct payment and not recurring. Can anyone help me with this?

```
function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL, $paymentStartdate) 
{

    $nvpstr="&AMT=". $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr .= "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr .= "&BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION=".urlencode("Denise Austin 360 Weekly Payments");
    $nvpstr .= "&BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments";
    $nvpstr .= "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
    $nvpstr .= "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
    $nvpstr .= "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
            $nvpstr .= "&PROFILESTARTDATE=" . urlencode($paymentStartdate);
            $nvpstr .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT=". urlencode($paymentStartdate);


    $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
    $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;
            $_SESSION["startdate"] = $paymentStartdate;

    $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
        $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
    }

    return $resArray;
}
```

As you can see i am trying to pass the startdate in the field PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT but when i get into the order confirmation part and i call $GetExpressCheckoutDetails($token), all that is returned is:

`Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-6JB06756S20069824
    [BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS] => 1
    [CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-11-22T23:58:03Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => cfd8d79420c2f
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 84
    [BUILD] => 13630372
    [EMAIL] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [PAYERID] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
    [FIRSTNAME] => Test
    [LASTNAME] => Buyer
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTONAME] => Test Buyer
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => xxxxxxxx
    [SHIPTOCITY] => xxxxxxxx
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
    [SHIPTOZIP] => xxxxxxx
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United States
    [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AMT] => 14.99
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
    [TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
    [SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 14.99
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => Test Buyer
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => xxxxxxxxx
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United States
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
    [PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
)`

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have set up SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails & CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile. I got these function from: https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example/blob/master/paypalfunctions.php and alittle help from the Paypal Integration wizard. If i hard code the start date in the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile that it creates the recurring payment just fine. But i want my users to select a date they want to start on and pass that through to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

Comment: Are you starting the session prior to setting it?  You need to make sure you've got session_start() set before $_SESSION data will work on any given page.

Comment: Grrrr That did it. Forgot to do session_start(). thanks a bunch!!